# Will creating typefaces in Main thread affect App performance?

Tags: java, android, performance, typeface

I was wondering whether creating multiple typefaces and applying them to text views in the **main thread** affect the *performance* of my app. If so, how can I use them in a way that doesn't hinder the app performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you load the fonts at the beginning, there shouldn't be any other on-going performance penalties.